# URL dwell time in any programming language?

Tags: information-retrieval

Could you please give me some hints, websites, books or research papers that would explain how to calculate the URL dwell time.

in case you don't know what is dwell time : dwell time denotes the time which a user spends viewing a document after clicking a link on a search engine results page.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One crude way to do this on a page would be to use a small GET request on a timer, going to a server - an "I'm still here". The frequency of this would be a trade off. This would be relatively easy to do with jquery or a similar framework.

You would not know if it is actually in an abandoned tab or that it is open but not actually being looked at.

A sample for the client end (using jquery):

```
$session = Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000);

function still_alive() {
  $url = $server_url + "/still_alive";
  $.get($url, {location: location.href, session: $session});
}

// call it once to prime it
still_alive();

// Set it up on a timer
window.setTimeout(function() {
  still_alive();
}, 1000);
```

1000 is the interval in milliseconds - so this is on a 1 second interval. $server_url is the server to register this at - I am adding "/still_alive" as an endpoint to register this at. $session - this can be some way of identifying the current session  - set to something once when the page loads - it could be the result of a uuid function.

The next line is a Jquery GET request to that whole url. It is being passed a plain object - with the key location holding the url of the current location. It may be more appropriate to be a POST instead of a GET - but the principle is still the same.